# xscreensaver systemd user service init : wait for DISPLAY

Tags: systemd, services, xscreensaver

I have xscreensaver running as a user service and see that often it fails to start. The status shows `DISPLAY not set`.

I've changed the service definition to now retry and that seems to be working

```
 [Unit]
 Description=XScreenSaver
 StartLimitInterval=200
 StartLimitBurst=5

 [Service]
 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/xscreensaver -nosplash
 Restart=always
 RestartSec=30


 [Install]
 WantedBy=default.target
```

Is there a better way to do this? My guess is that because this is a user service it is starting sometimes before the user environment is fully set. 
Ideally the start would wait for DISPLAY to be set.

The restart strategy seems crude but perhaps that's the best I can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found your question, as for me it fails half the times.

```
[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xscreensaver -nosplash
```

UPDATE:

This is the content of my user xscreensaver systemd user unit, and it's working now 100%.
// ~/.config/systemd/user/xscreensaver.service

```
[Unit]
Description=XScreenSaver
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xscreensaver -nosplash
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30s

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

I think it was failing because it tried to start it once and no graphical session was ready yet (sometimes it was, for what I recall half the times).

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean that with this  `Environment` setting it fails half the time? Or that this setting fixes the failures.